# Make a list of cities within a district and districts within cities

Tags: arcgis

I have about 800 "district" polygons in one shapefile, and another shapefile with all cities in a state and the counties they fall into. I need to figure out where the districts are in relation to places and counties and put them ultimately into a CSV. The table will be something like:

[image: example table]

Spatial Join gives me 1,346 records. Merge is also unwieldy. Since my ultimate goal is a CSV, I could export a table & clean it up in Excel, or with Python if it's not too complicated. Any direction will be appreciated!

Update: Find Overlaps is suggested below, but I did a test on 10 records and can't think of a way to use this output:

[image]

Comment: It seems you need to start reading this: [Find Overlaps (Intelligence)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/intelligence/find-overlaps.htm) ?

Comment: That only tells me how many polygons overlap a given polygon. I am hoping to make a simple list (as opposed to multiple lines as with a Join) of which overlap, as in my table above.

Comment: I the polygon of a city not overlapped by the polygon of the county, which is overlapped by the polygon of the state ?