# Capture all polygons overlapping, containing other polygons (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have a shapefile of district polygons and a shapefile of Census Places and the Counties that contain them.

I need a systematic way to to capture:

1. Which districts fall into which cities and counties
2. Which cities/counties fall into which districts
3. Where a district may exclude cities or other districts.

For instance (Co = County, P = Place, D = District):
[image: Polygon configuration]

This is what I'm ultimately after:
[image: Table1]

Which means:

- D3 is completely contained by Co1, P2, & D4.
- D4 is completely contained by Co1 & P2
- D2 is completely contained by Co1
- D1 covers all of Co2 except for P4, P5, and P6

  - D1 also bleeds into Co1 and P3 a bit
- Sometimes districts completely overlap each other. There could be a D5 that also covers all of County2 except the 3 Places.

But I will be happy just to have all the overlapping, contained, and excluded listed individually:
[image: Table2]
I think my Python script combines all the rows accurately into my ultimate goal (Table1), if I can't do it with Arc.

I've used Spatial Join "within" and "contains" and thrown the results into one spreadsheet & tried to wrangle the data so there aren't duplicates. There are over 800 districts and all their overlaps, I can't figure out how to QA effectively. I have no idea how to deal with the "excluded" issue.

I put the cart before the horse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77295934/make-a-list-of-cities-within-a-district-and-districts-within-cities), but I've realized my polygon data need work before I can move to the CSV phase with any confidence.